# Is there any way to exit "less" without clearing the screen?

Tags: less, termcap

Relatively often, I find myself wanting to quit `less` but leave what I was viewing on the screen, to refer back to. Is there any way to do this? Workarounds?

(My current workaround is to quit, then use `more`. So any workaround that's better than that is welcomed. The ideal would be something I can use once I'm already inside `less`, perhaps with a shell setting or some scripting.)

My desktop is OSX, but I use RHEL and Ubuntu servers.

Comment: Reading a long output (as in `git diff` or `git log`) in `less -X` will take up the scroll buffer in my terminal and evict much of the previous output. I'd love it if `less` could just exit with the last screenful of output at the time of the exit; i.e. no more than one page of the scroll buffer would be taken after quitting `less`. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, `-R` is usually a safer choice than `-r`.

Comment: Thanks. For those wondering: `-R is "Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly in most cases."`

Comment: @musiphil Perhaps -c?

Comment: @MatthewPhipps: I guess `-c` is about how to update the screen when you move around inside `less`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This is actually a function of the terminal emulator you are using (xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, screen). An alternate screen, or altscreen, gets launched when programs such as `less` or `vim` are invoked. This altscreen has no history buffer and exits immediately when you quit the program, switching back to the original screen which restores the previous window content history and placement.

You can prevent `less` from launch in an altscreen by passing the argument "-X".

`less -X /path/to/some/file`

You can also pass "-X" as an environment variable. So if you are using `bash`, place this in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LESS="-X"
```

However, this disbles the termcap (terminal capability) initialization and deinitialization, so other views when you use `less` may appear off.

Another option would be to use `screen` and set the option `altscreen off` in your `~/.screenrc`. `less` will not clear the screen and should preserve color formatting. Presumably `tmux` will have the same option.

This [blog entry](http://fixlog.blogspot.com/2006/09/stop-gnome-terminal-screen-clear.html) describes the problem and offers some different solutions specific to `gnome-terminal` with varying success.

Comment: Perfect. Is there a downside?

Comment: @SteveBennett Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Wait, I've discovered one already - the output of `git log` (and probably other coloured commands) is messed up.

Comment: You're right. -X disable the termcap initialization and deinitialization. Hmmm.

Comment: well, it's still useful - I make a script "les" on my path, which calls `less -X $@`. And saves a keystroke :)

Comment: @SteveBennett See my edit. Try using "screen" and disabling altscreen.

Comment: @SteveBennett That's small enough I'd make it an alias: `alias les="/usr/bin/less -X"`

Comment: Hey, I think I just discovered an antidote to the `git log` issue above: `export LESS="-r -X"`. (No idea what the side-effects of *that* are...)

Comment: Actually, `git` sets the `LESS` variable to `FRSX` if it is unset when it runs the pager, so you can just leave `LESS` unset and `less` will automatically run with `-FRSX`. Look for `core.pager` in `git-config(1)` for more information.

Comment: This does it for me for now (in cygwin), but my ideal solution would (a) default to not clearing the screen and (b) add to the pager an option to exit removing its output. Obviously (a) is for “**Exactly what I wanted to know**” and (b) for “_That wasn’t much use_”.

Comment: Awesome!!! My problem was the exact opposite. I run `screen` and use `vim` as my editor and it is convenient to sometimes suspend it (CTRL-Z) and see the history, output of compilation and so on. So the solution for me was to add `altscreen on` in `~/.screenrc`.

Comment: @GeorgeM was there something wrong with [my edit of this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/38638/7)? you make no mention of a problem in [your rollback message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/38638/8).

Comment: @jah Your edit did not substantially improve the answer. You added opinion as to what the "best" solution was from a blog post. If you have a solution which you feel is "best", it should be in it's own answer.

Comment: I just sent an email to the creator of less, Mark Nudelman, asking him to weigh in.

Comment: I think we should ask the question to the problem in a slightly different way.

How to make `less` re-print the last screen after the -X deinitialization strings to the terminal before it exit ? 

So that we don't have to copy is ahead or to use two terminal

Comment: @SteveBennett a downside is that this disables mouse scrolling. You can often re-enable it with `less -X --mouse`

Answer (score 23):

The way I remember this is `less -SEX` for when I need to dump output to the screen but don't want lines to wrap. For example `docker ps | less -SEX` What that does is this:

- `-S`

  - Scroll instead of wrap
  - If you drop the `-E`, you can use your arrow keys to scroll
- `-E`

  - Exit when you reach the EOF
- `-X`

  - Prevent term swapping/blanking
  - The "memory" part is that I know what S and E does, so this must be the other part. (And our reason for committing this command to memory is that we want to dump (not enter an interactive session) unwrapped output.

If you can't remember `less -SEX`, there's not a lot of hope for you. Just re-google every time I guess.

Comment: The guy has a problem and you offer him less sex?

Comment: export LESS="-SEX"

Answer (score 7):

George's solution didn't work for me, but this solution did (from the [blog entry](http://fixlog.blogspot.com/2006/09/stop-gnome-terminal-screen-clear.html) linked in his answer).

1. `$ infocmp -I xterm > ~/xterm-noclear.src`
2. Edit ~/xterm-noclear.src

   - change the name on the second line from 'xterm' to 'xterm-noclear', or whatever suits you (also change 'xterm-debian' if it's present)
   - remove the instructions 'smcup' and 'rmcup' (e.g. "smcup=\E[?1049h, " and "rmcup=\E[?1049l, ")
3. `$ mkdir ~/.terminfo`
4. `$ tic ~/xterm-noclear.src` (x/xterm-noclear should appear in your ~/.terminfo directory)
5. `$ export TERM=xterm-noclear` (now check the behaviour of less and, if satisfied, add the export directive line to your ~/.profile)

(I copied these instructions directly from @jah's rejected edit of George's answer.)

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier way. Just pipe the command to "cat" command

```
less blah.txt|cat
```

and it works not only for "less" but also other similar command which create a "new" terminal to print the output (git log for example)

Comment: Not quite the full solution. It doesn't work if you're piping into less. For example `cat some_long_text_file.txt | less | cat` the cat chases its tail.