# How does "man" restore the screen when I quit the program?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, man

If I open a man page of a program like `cat` or `ls`, it prints (may not be the appropriate word) the contents of the man page and when I press `q`, it shows the screen just like before invoking the `man` command. How does the restore happen? What erases everything and then prints the previous contents of the shell?

Example:

```
[VAR121@Tesla Testing]$  man ls
```

Output:

```
LS(1)                                                        User Commands                                                        LS(1)

NAME
       ls - list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
       ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...

 ............
```

When I press `q`, the screen goes back to shells default appearance, such as the prompt shown below.

```
[VAR121@Tesla Testing]$  man ls
[VAR121@Tesla Testing]$
```

How is the screen restored ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Clearing" and "restoring" the screen is actually a function of the terminal emulator you are using (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, `screen`).

By default, the pager that `man` uses is `less`.

From `man 1 man`

```
   -P  pager
          Specify  which pager to use.  This option overrides the 
          MANPAGER environment variable, which in turn overrides 
          the PAGER variable.  By default, man  uses /usr/bin/less -is.
```

When `less` is invoked, an altscreen is launched by the terminal emulator to display the contents of the man page. When `less` exits, the altscreen is destroyed and the terminal displays what was saved in the buffer.

There is an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38634/is-there-any-way-to-exit-less-without-clearing-the-screen/38638#38638) which discusses this further and how to keep programs like `less` from launching an altscreen and thus clearing the screen when it exits. In a nutshell, you could define an environment variable so that `less` does not launch an altscreen on invocation. If you are using bash, place this in ~/.bashrc:

`export MANPAGER="/usr/bin/less -r -X -is"`

Comment: Same story with `vi` too?

Comment: vim honors the altscreen in your terminal emulator. You could add something like this to your ~/.vimrc - "set t_ti= t_te=" to change the terminal capabilities vim uses.