# Oh-my-zsh deletes output of successful command with "FAIL: 141"

Tags: zsh, git, oh-my-zsh, pager

My Oh-my-zsh does the following:

1. When I run the `git log --pretty --oneline` command, it shows me a long list of commits, as expected.
2. As soon as I hit <kbd>q</kbd>, it suddenly disappears with the below output:

   ```
   $ git log --pretty --oneline
   FAIL: 141
   ```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `git` failed because it was killed by the system when it tried to write to a broken pipe. It's good that you have configuration in place that notifies you when a command you run fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number after “FAIL” is the process's exit status. A process's exit status, as reported by the shell, is generally¹:

- 0 if the program exited normally and reported a success.
- 1 to 125 if the program exited normally and reported an error.
- 128+*s* if the program was killed by [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) *s*, where *s* is a small integer.

141 means signal 13 which is [SIGPIPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE). Under the hood, the git command sets up a pipe between two subcommands: one subcommand gathers data and writes data to the pipe, and the other subcommand is the [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)). If you don't view the whole output, the pager exits without waiting for the first subcommand to exit. When the first subcommand next tries to write to the pipe, it is killed by SIGPIPE. This is normal behavior, to avoid having commands continue to calculate and write output that nothing is reading.

There's nothing to fix. But if you find this distracting, you can change your theme to not report a failure status when it's SIGPIPE. The way to do that depends on your oh-my-zsh theme, but from what I can see with a quick look (I don't use oh-my-zsh), the ones that have the word FAIL do it by setting the `PROMPT` variable, using a [prompt expansion conditional](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts) to only print the FAIL stuff if the command's exit status is nonzero. So you'd need to change that to also take the “no-failure” branch if the exit status is 141. If you're using a theme bundled with oh-my-zsh, look for `FAIL` in the theme definition `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme`. Let's take the example of `dst.zsh-theme`: the definition is

```
PROMPT='%(?, ,%{$fg[red]%}FAIL%{$reset_color%}
)
%{$fg[magenta]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[yellow]%}%m%{$reset_color%}: %{$fg_bold[blue]%}%~%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info)
$(prompt_char) '
```

(Note that it spans multiple lines.) The general pattern is `%(?,IFSUCCESS,IFFAILURE)` to print `IFSUCCESS` on success (`$?` equals 0) and `IFFAILURE` on failure (including signals). So we'll add another condition if `$?` equals 141:

```
PROMPT='%(141?, ,%(?, ,%{$fg[red]%}FAIL%{$reset_color%}
))
%{$fg[magenta]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[yellow]%}%m%{$reset_color%}: %{$fg_bold[blue]%}%~%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info)
$(prompt_char) '
```

(Note that in addition to prepending `%(141?, ,`, there's a matching closing parenthesis on the second line.)

¹  <sub>The details are off-topic here.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant! thanks for the explanation. It no longer shows me the failure. It does, however, remove the log output when I hit `q`. Is this a git problem or ZSH problem? thanks

Comment: Nevermind, it's a `git` thing. Found the solution here: https://serebrov.github.io/html/2014-01-04-git-log-and-less-keep-output.html

Comment: @ritratt You mean the output of git is hidden when you exit the pager? Neither: it's the pager and to some extent the terminal, and it happens regardless of whether git was interrupted. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38634/is-there-any-way-to-exit-less-without-clearing-the-screen/38638#38638